# how to route a button in laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel

How can I pass a parameter in URL, like `type=Wedding`, then query DB accordingly and pass it to a view in laravel?

```
<div class="row row-bottom-padded-md">    
  <div align="center">
    <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="all">All</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="pre_wedding">Pre-Wedding</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="holud">Holud</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="wedding">Wedding</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="reception">Reception</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="post_wedding">Post Wedding</button>
  </div>
  <br/>

  @forelse($gallerypictures as $gallerypicture)
  <div class="gallery_product col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 filter">
    <div class="products">
      <img src="{{url('images',$gallerypicture->image)}}">
      <div class="overlays">
        <div class="text_color">Hello World</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  @empty
  <h3>No Photos</h3>
  @endforelse    
</div>
```

The code works well when I search `http://127.0.0.1:8000/gallery/wedding`. But I want to show products category when I click the button. How can I solve it?

Comment: Use anchor tab and give it the class same as button

Comment: can't understand show me your code please...

Answer (score 2):

From what I understood you wanted to show something on wedding page when the user click the wedding button .
What you can do is instead of declaring the button declare the anchor tag in the blade file like this

```
 <a href="/gallery/wedding" class="btn btn-default filter-button">Button </a>
```

Instead of doing it this way

```
<button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="wedding">Wedding</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are looking something like this  `http://127.0.0.1:8000/gallery/wedding?a=1&b=2`
Here `?a=1&b=2` is called query string. On your action method you can grab value of a by get method(eg: `$_GET['a']`)

So in your case `http://127.0.0.1:8000/gallery/wedding?type=Wedding` do something like this
and grab the value by `$_GET['type']` .

Hope this will help.

Comment: Is it what you wanted @FarjanaHasan ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this `<a>` tag to redirect to another page instead of button

```
<a href="/gallery?type=wedding" class="btn btn-default filter-button">Wedding</a>
```

You can get this type parameter value in your laravel view file by using this below code

```
@php
$queryParam = Request::query('type');
@endphp

{{$queryParam}}
```